# How can I copy files from windows to linux using bash script

Tags: linux, windows, cmake, cross-platform

Im using cmake and visual studio 2019 to build my project on a remote linux machine.
At the end of the compilation Im using cmake POST_BUILD option
to run a sh script on the linux machine.
The script creates a tgz file with all my compilation products.
How can I, in that sh running on my linux machine, get a file from a windows machine in order to include it in my tgz?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file transfer program supporting a file transfer protocol like SFTP. You can install the OpenSSH program on both machines and set them up to be able to communicate with one another. Then you can run the file transfer command in CMake as [a post-build custom command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events).

Answer (score 0):

To start off, you should go into the properties of your Windows folder and allow sharing of the folder with your Linux machine (or everyone, if you are in a secure network). Then, you you can use smbclient to copy the files from the Windows path to your Linux machine, as shown in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168484/550131).